# Define variable global not local

Tags: node.js

I have some issues to use a global variable in my node.js app. 
I use:

```
app.locals.isTestCafeRunning = false;
```

I think the problem here is locals, I think this variable is only valid inside the browser session, not inside the global app.

I want to use this variable in the main route:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    async function getListData(){
        var myListOptions = "";
        var myListText = "";

        arrayTestcaseData = await getMongojson();

        /*code cut*/

        var inPlaceButton = "";
        if(req.app.locals.isTestCafeRunning===false){
            inPlaceButton = "<button id=\"myButton\">Testrun starten</button>";
        }else{
            inPlaceButton = "<strong>Clipcafe in Benutzung!</strong>";
        }
        myHtmlCode = myHtmlCode.replace("%%BUTTON%%",inPlaceButton);
        res.send(myHtmlCode);

    }

    getListData();

});
```

I want to fill the variable in

```
app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {

        //Function start Testcafe?
        createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
            .then(tc => {
                testcafe     = tc;
                const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

                req.app.locals.isTestCafeRunning = true;
                inputStore.clLogin = req.body.name; 
                inputStore.clPassword = req.body.pass;
                inputStore.metaFolder = '19233456';
                inputStore.metaUrl = req.body.channel;

                return runner
                    .src(['tests/temp.js'])
                    .browsers(myBrowser)
                    //.browsers('browserstack:Chrome')
                    .screenshots('allure/screenshots/', true)
                    .reporter('allure')
                    .run();
            })
            .then(failedCount => {
                req.app.locals.isTestCafeRunning = false;
                console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
                testcafe.close();
                startReportGenerator();
                res.sendStatus(201);
            });


});
```

But I want to have this global not local vor all users, so if user 1 starts TestCafe, user 2 will only see "In use".

Comment: `app.locals` are a server feature, they are not accessible from the browser. Plus values set in `app.locals` are accessible across the entire app thus to some degree are global (they just wouldn't be global across multiple instances). What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to show the use who connect to the node server that a test instance is in progress. Like to hide the Start Button.